# Android Studio отказано в доступе

Tags: android-studio

Часто бывает, что при попытке build своего приложения у меня кидает ошибку Отказано в доступе.

Если подробно посмотреть то это из-за этой ошибки

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > java.io.IOException: Failed to create 'D:\Project\Peshkariki-Old\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
```

Но я не понимаю почему это происходит, ведь я запускаю Android Studio от прав администратора. Помогает только перезапуск Windows. Кто может помочь?

Comment: а если не от имени админа запускать?

Comment: @Andrew тоже самое